# GSignal "instance X has no handler with id Y" errors

Tags: gtk, wxwidgets, glib

I'm doing a bit of code cleanup in a wxWidgets/gtk application, and would like to fix these warnings, as they seem indicative of a bug:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /tmp/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2579: instance '0x2d61440' has no handler with id '3133'
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /tmp/buildd/glib2.0-2.42.1/./gobject/gsignal.c:2579: instance '0x2d4a8e0' has no handler with id '2924'
```

Is there a good way to resolve the instance pointer and handler ID to an object and an event, so I can find out what handler is missing here, or how would I identify the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify the source of the problem, it can help to run the program under gdb and put a breakpoint on `g_log` function, then look at the stack (`bt`) when it is hit.